# Perform Audio FFT and Calibrate to Equivalent Measured SPL

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am looking to get calibrated RMS FFTs from audio data collected by a sound level meter recorded over 10second periods:

- the SLM took equivalent measurements of the overall sound pressure levels (in 10s periods) alongside the audio recordings;
- the SLM was calibrated to 94dB at a ref frequency of 1000Hz prior to recording / measurement;
- the audio data has been recorded at 12000 samples / second, so each 10sec file = 10 * 12000 = 120000 samples

I would like to undertake RMS FFTs of the recordings, get their calibrated SPL value, and output each FFT to a resolution of 1Hz (spacing). I am only interested in the range 0-2000Hz.

I have set up a Python script which I think achieves what I require in terms of performing the RMS FFT (assuming there aren't any jarring mistakes in the script), but haven't been able to figure out how to calibrate the FFT's based on the sound pressure level readings made by the sound level meter.

Currently the FFT outputs are all negative values;

[image]

The equivalent 10s measured sound pressure levels, include both the overall level, and 1/3 octave bands levels..;

[image]

How do I calibrate the FFT's to output the sound pressure level? I assume it wouldn't simply be a case of adding the equivalent 10second measured sound pressure level to the FFT's (or something along those lines)?

I can also send my full script and an example 10s audio file, and also equivalent 10s sound pressure levels (if of interest);

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import csv
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack
from scipy.signal import hanning


minFreq = 0
maxFreq = 2000

N = 12000 
fs = 12000
fs_res = fs / N # Assume this is correct given requirement for 1Hz spacing?

MaxHzLines = int(maxFreq/fs_res)

overlap = 0
window = N / fs 
skip = window * (1 - overlap)

# Pull audio data in (np array([-54, -55, -56, ..., -86, -94, -98]) of len 120000
audiodata = pullAudioData(ws_dir) 

# define func to split audio data into chunks (for rms averaging)
def enframe(x, S, L):
  w = np.hanning(L)
  frames = []
  nframes = 1 + int((len(x) - L) / S)
  for t in range(0, nframes):
    frames.append(np.copy(x[(t * S):(t * S + L)]) * w)

  dfFrames = pd.DataFrame({'frames': frames})

  return dfFrames

# Break data into 10*12000 chunks.. 
dfFrames = enframe(audiodata,
                   int(skip * 12000),
                   int(window * 12000))

# ..which will return df with split data per row (10*12000 chunks);
'''
                                              frames
0  [-0.0, -3.7702688351903824e-06, -1.53552756598...
1  [0.0, 7.540537670380765e-06, 3.071055131975697...
2  [-0.0, -3.15331575306832e-06, -1.1790658095978...
3  [0.0, 8.363141779876848e-06, 3.31783634793803e...
4  [0.0, 8.226041094960834e-07, 4.11302026603888e...
5  [-0.0, -5.484027396640556e-07, -2.193610808554...
6  [0.0, 3.6331681502743685e-06, 1.56294770109477...
7  [0.0, 5.484027396640556e-06, 2.138770538340217...
8  [-0.0, -3.5646178078163615e-06, -1.34358662023...
9  [0.0, 8.77444383462489e-06, 3.592037699007289e...                    
'''

# define func to FFT data
def stft(dfFrames, N, endIdx, fs, Fmin, Fmax):
  startIdx = int(np.floor((endIdx / Fmax) * Fmin))
  
  # Perform FFT on each windowed frame
  stft_frames = [fftpack.fft(x)[startIdx:endIdx] for x in dfFrames['frames']]
  
  freq_axis = {idx: round(m*fs/N, 5) for idx, m in enumerate(range(0, endIdx))}  
  
  dfSTFT = pd.DataFrame({'freq_axis': freq_axis})

  dfSTFT = dfSTFT.rename(index=freq_axis)

  for idx, frame in enumerate(stft_frames):
    dfSTFT[idx] = frame

  dfSTFT = dfSTFT.drop('freq_axis', axis=1)

  return dfSTFT

# FFT data chunks
dfSTFT = stft(dfFrames, N, MaxHzLines, fs, minFreq, maxFreq)

# FFT Analysis
# Get rms averaged narrowband spectra
FFT_data_real = 2/N*abs(dfSTFT)
rms_averaged = np.sqrt(np.mean(FFT_data_real**2, axis=1))
dfSTFT_narrow = pd.DataFrame({"narrow": rms_averaged}, index = dfSTFT.index)

# Get dB values
dfSTFT_narrow = 20*np.log10(dfSTFT_narrow)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SPL is time-domain, not frequency like FFT. I.e. shouldn't you calculate the SPL from the sample directly?

Comment: Thanks @balmy, though I'm not quite sure where I would start with attempting that calculation? Would you have any idea at all?

Comment: Actually, would it just be a case of taking the SPL at 1000Hz, and raising the whole FFT up to that same level using the FFT value at 1000Hz..?